# Variable exchange between directive and controller in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I know this has been asked loads of times but I can't seem to find an appropriate answer for my case.

At the moment I have a form to "invite more people" that takes a name and email. 
Underneath that form is a button "invite more friends" that will trigger a directive "add-more-person" which will add another form.

I want people to not be able to invite more than 10 friends. when there are 10 'invite-a-friend-forms' I want the button to be hidden.

So I added a counter in the directive so that you won't be able to add more forms after there are 10, and a boolean "addFriends" to my controller.

Now I want my boolean addFriends to be changed to false whenever the directive's counter reaches a certain amount.

I can't achieve this using $watch since I'm not using $scope and all the other things I tried have failed aswell.

This is what my code looks like:

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="column medium-6">                
           <button ng-show="post.addFriends" class="btn-grey" type="button" add-more-person add-friends="post.addFriends">Invite more people</button>
      </div>
      <div class="column medium-6">
             <button class="btn-green" type="button">Send</button>
     </div>
</div>
```

directive:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular.module('app').directive('addMorePerson', addMorePerson);

function addMorePerson($rootScope, $window, $timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            addFriends: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
            var counter = 0;
            console.log('start: ' + scope.addFriends);

            elem.bind('click', appendInput);

            function appendInput() {

                if(counter < 2) {
                    var myEl = angular.element(document.querySelector('#content-form'));

                    var template = '<div class="content">' +
                        '<div class="form-page">' +
                        '<div class="form-field">' +
                        '<label class="form-label">Naam:</label>' +
                        '<div class="form-controls">' +
                        '<input kl_virtual_keyboard_secure_input="on" type="text">' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div class="form-field">' +
                        '<label class="form-label">E-mail <span>(verplicht)</span>:</label>' +
                        '<div class="form-controls">' +
                         '<input type="email">' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '</div>';
                    myEl.append(template);
                    counter++;
                } else {
                   scope.addFriends = false;
                   console.log('after: ' + scope.addFriends);
                   return;
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
})();
```

and Controller:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('PostDonateController', postDonateController);

function postDonateController(apiFactory, $sessionStorage, $localStorage, $state, $stateParams) {

    var that = this; // jshint ignore: line

    that.addFriends = true;

}
})();
```

I left out all my other code to make it more readable. So my console logs in the directive tell me that it does indeed start at true and after 3 clicks it turns to false. But this value is not passed on to my controller and therefore not hiding the button. Any ideas how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call `scope.$apply();` at list line of your append function, it'll perform sync between directive and controller. You should do that because you append template outside of angular context.

But your solution is awkward, you should append templates via ng-repeat.

Comment: Thank you so much! $apply() fixed it.
Also I don't know how I would use ng-repeat without an array/collection of templates, since I only have 1 template.

Comment: Why don't you use ng-include than?

Comment: I'm just doing an internship at this web development company, I only just started learning angular so I don't know the best ways to do things yet..
Its already hard enough for me to work without $scope !